# Why do ``PasswordEncoder`` implementations use hardcoded UTF-8 in Spring Security 5.x as input?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, utf-8, character-encoding

I have just stumbled across an unexpected behaviour with Spring Security 5.x: The provided `PasswordEncoder` implementations use UTF-8 encoding for the data to be hashed in a *hardcoded* way (examples: [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.java#L122), [BCrpyt](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L735)). So there is neither a way to inject another encoding nor to configure this behaviour in any way.

Now I am curious to know, *why* this design decision has been made? (And I have no doubt that this was a *profound* decision; we are talking about Spring anyway!)

I have nothing discovered within their official [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), nor do they say something within their [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/api/). I would have expected to find more information about this design decision to be honest. And if not as a *rationale* then at minimum an explicit documentation about this fact. (Searching is of course a bit difficult as we have a *semantic* collision when it comes to *encoding* questions dealing with hashing... perhaps I really have overlooked it?)

My initial problem was, that I have to deal with a legacy system, where the password hash is created with *<s>ISO-8859-1</s> CP-1252* encoding as base for the hashing and so the matching in my Spring Boot 2 app failed. Of course I can solve this by just letting change the legacy system - I am very lucky that I don't have to maintain the legacy app .

But I still wonder, why the *easy* solution (defining the appropriate *LATIN1* encoding for the encoder in Spring a la `spring.security.crypto.encoding=cp-1252`) does not work here.

This seems to be contrary to the whole rest of Spring, where you can configure almost everything if you need or want to. That's why I ask this question here.

**Edit:** I have just learned that MySQL besides [*UTF-8*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) also failed to name their [*LATIN1*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-we-sets.html) encoding in the right way: *CP-1252* (or *WINDOWS-1252* if you prefer). So my assumption about the *ISO-8859-1* encoding was wrong. In the end that does not affect the problem itself!

Comment: A good reason is that UTF8 supports any Unicode character that a user might choose to use in his/her password, whereas ISO-8859-1 only support a very short list (latin characters). So using UTF-8 makes it work for any password, in any language, whereas ISO-8859-1 would produce the same sequence of bytes for all the passwords using non-latin characters, making it very unsafe.

Comment: @jb-nizet: I am totally aware of the fact, that UTF-8 opens up the range of characters. So it's a very good *default* of course. But why *hardcoded*?

Comment: Well, you can provide your own password encoder, can't you?

Comment: @UChef I couldn't find a better reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history): *The specification was revised to specify that when hashing strings: - the string must be UTF-8 encoded*.

Comment: @UChef I would say for Digist the specification also requires UTF-8, see [RFC 7616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7616#section-3.4).

Answer (score 0):

First, I should note that speculative questions can be tricky to answer. Even though I commit frequently to the Spring Security project, my thoughts here aren't official, and I invite you to take my words with a grain of salt.

This question "why hasn't X open source project exposed Y thing yet?" basically comes down to a few things:

- The programming practice is common enough that adding a hook to deviate from it can be more confusing than helpful to users
- Any hook added is a hook maintained in perpetuity. The deprecation cycle is very long
- Users already have a simple alternative
- Exposing a hook would be inconsistent with similar places in the code
- Deviating from the programming practice is insecure/bad practice/etc., so maintainers want to make sure it's straight-forward to override, but not necessarily just a switch-flip

Combining these with the fact that `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` is `@Deprecated` just means that the case for adding simply needs to be a strong one.

Since no strong case has yet been made, the feature does not exist. This is true for any other aspect of `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` that isn't configurable, too (like the format of the final encoding).

In lieu of that, @jb-nizet pointed out that it's pretty straightforward to [expose your own encoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-password-encoding) (and to use the password encoder API to migrate your passwords). Or, if that doesn't work for you, then [log a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new) with the team, and we'll take a look!